# Pact - how to write expectations on requests?

Tags: pact

I have successfully run expectations on the response that the provider gives. Now, how can I write expectations to make sure that the things that I am sending to the provider as a consumer are correct?

That is, how do you ensure that the request parameters are the expected ones?

Comment: How did you run the expectations on the response that the Provider gives without first writing the consumer test? Can you please post example code or a gist?

Comment: Also, which language are you using?